# Type Mismatch Error in a simple VBA matrix code

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub MacroTemp()

   Dim i, j As Integer
   Dim c(1, 1) As Double
   For i = 0 To 1
        For j = 0 To 1
            c(i, j) = i + j
            Sheets(Sheet2).Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value = c(i, j)
         Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

It is showing Type Mismatch Error.So what is wrong in this code?

Comment: Is `Sheet2` the name of your worksheet?  If so, change `Sheets(Sheet2)` to `Sheets("Sheet2")`.  If you are trying to use the [code name](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm) of the sheet, and `Sheet2` is the code name, try `Sheet2.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value = c(i, j)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are referencing `Sheet2` correctly.

If `Sheet2` is the name of your worksheet, then you can reference it like so:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value = c(i, j)
```

Alternatively, if `Sheet2` is the [code name](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm) of the worksheet that you are referring to, you can use this:

```
Sheet2.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value = c(i, j)
```

I am assuming you haven't declared a string variable `Sheet2` anywhere.